# C ++: Finding the Maximum, Minimum, Sum and Average

Tags: c++

I am currently working on some code for my C++ class, and I cant find what I'm doing wrong. My code will not output the correct number value. My code is supposed to be able to Finding the Maximum, Minimum, Sum and Average of any set number array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12; // number of elements 
    int userVals[ARRAY_SIZE];// Array of input numbers
    int numArray[] ={24, -5, 72, 104, 0, 5, 89, -225, 19, 17, 16, 
    81};//Elements
    int i; // loop index
    int maxVal; // Max Value
    int minVal; // Min Value
    int sumVal; // Sum Value
    int aveVal; // Average Value

    sumVal = 0; //* Sum Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        sumVal = sumVal + userVals[i];
    }
    cout << " Sum Value: " << sumVal << endl;

    maxVal = userVals[0];//* Max Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
         if (userVals[i] > maxVal) {
              maxVal = userVals[i];
         }
    }
    cout << " Max Value: " << maxVal << endl;

    minVal = userVals[0];//* Min Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (userVals[i] > minVal) {
            minVal = userVals[i];
        }
    }
    cout << " Min Value: " << minVal << endl;

    aveVal = userVals[0];//* Average Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
         aveVal = aveVal + userVals[i];
    }
    cout << " Average Value: " << aveVal << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Like I stated above, my code is supposed to be able to be able to Finding the Maximum, Minimum, Sum and Average of any set number array. Currently, when I run my code it outputs these results:

Sum Value: 447815718

Max Value: 914973176

Min Value: 914973176

Average Value: 1362788894

Edits 7/13/19:

These are the changes I made to the code to make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12; // number of elements 
    int userVals[ARRAY_SIZE];// Array of input numbers
    int numArray[] ={24, -5, 72, 104, 0, 5, 89, -225, 19, 17, 16, 81}; // 
    Elements
    int i; // loop index
    int maxVal; // Max Value
    int minVal; // Min Value
    int sumVal; // Sum Value
    int aveVal; // Average Value


    sumVal = 0; //* Sum Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        sumVal = sumVal + numArray[i];
    }
    cout << " Sum Value: " << sumVal << endl;

    maxVal = numArray[0];//* Max Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (numArray[i] > maxVal) {
          maxVal = numArray[i];
        }
    }
    cout << " Max Value: " << maxVal << endl;

    minVal = numArray[0];//* Min Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (numArray[i] < minVal) {
         minVal = numArray[i];
        }
    }
    cout << " Min Value: " << minVal << endl;

    aveVal = numArray[0];//* Average Value

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (aveVal = numArray[0] + numArray[1] + numArray[2] + numArray[3] + 
          numArray[4] + numArray[5] + numArray[6] + numArray[7] + 
          numArray[8] + numArray[9] + numArray[10] + numArray[11])
            aveVal = aveVal / 12;
    }
    cout << " Average Value: " << aveVal << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are filling `userVals` array ?

Comment: You didn't have initialized `userVals`, so you are getting garbage values. As you have put in include section, use `vector` instead of plain array

Comment: Why don't you change numArray to userVals and remove the first two lines. Looks like this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ Amadeus im still new at vectors so i didnt use them in the code and @rafix07 i was using it as user input or numArray.

Comment: @Nikhil Sahu you make a good point, im a novice at C++, so i still make silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value and the sum should be OK.

You are finding the maximum instead of the minimum because for a value to be the new minimum value it should be less than the current minimum so it should be:

```
...
if (userVals[i] < minVal) {
...
```

instead of:

```
...
if(userVals[i] > minVal){
...
```

And for the average you should divide the sum by the ARRAY_SIZE.

Also be careful because you are not initializing userVals.

Comment: thank you this is very informative, i made the changes to my code according to your information and it worked. it not only worked with my given number but any others i typed in as well.                                                                                                             
SIDENOTE: thank you for editing my post i'm new, so i still don't know the in's and out's of the website.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are referring to `userVals`, which never gets initialized. Use `numArray` instead.

BTW: You should probably rethink the way you calculate the average...

Comment: This worked like a charm ! thank you, I also made a couple of other changes to the code. i will post it up above just in case some one else has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library provides everything you need in the [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header.

To find the minimum and maximum, use [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

To find the sum, use [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

To find the average, use  [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) and divide by the number of elements.